# Use command-line Ant to build Eclipse Ant project

Tags: eclipse, command-line, ant, terminal

For my current project I need to run the build of our Java projects. But for the current task I am doing, Eclipse is not helping at all. All tools I need are not integrated in Eclipse, everything I do in Eclipse is clicking the Ant tasks. So is there a way to just do it by command line?

Simply calling the command arguments for Ant does not work.

I am running on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Can you detail how you are trying to run Ant, and what errors are showing?

Comment: I build with ant all the time outside of Eclipse which my developers use. What type of errors are you getting? Could it be due to the Eclipse Java compiler vs. the standard Java compiler? Could it be a classpath issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the command-line builder with the following command.

```
eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -data %WORKSPACE%
```

For more information see *[Headless Building with APT in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_apt_building_with_apt.htm)*.