# incremental build using eclipse command line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

REF: [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)

@kieveli

Is there any command to compile/build only modified files instead of whole project using eclipse command line?

Below command compiles the whole project every time.

```
eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "D:\Source\MyProject\workspace" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CORE_JAVA_BUILD_RECREATE_MODIFIED_CLASS_FILES_IN_OUTPUT_FOLDER` option:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.builder.recreateModifiedClassFileInOutputFolder=ignore
```

> public static final String CORE_JAVA_BUILD_RECREATE_MODIFIED_CLASS_FILES_IN_OUTPUT_FOLDER
>
> Core option ID: Recreate Modified class files in Output Folder.
>   Indicate whether the JavaBuilder should check for any changes to .class files in the output folders while performing incremental build operations. If changes are detected to managed .class files, then a full build is performed, otherwise the changes are left as is. Tools further altering generated .class files, like optimizers, should ensure this option remains set in its default state of ignore.
>
> Option id:
>   "org.eclipse.jdt.core.builder.recreateModifiedClassFileInOutputFolder"
>
> Possible values:
>   { "enabled", "ignore" }
>
> Default:
>   "ignore"
>
> Since:
>   3.2

Or the `org.eclipse.core.resources.ant.IncrementalBuild` Ant task:

> eclipse.incrementalBuild
>
> When the project attribute is supplied, this task is a wrapper to IProject.build(). Otherwise, this task is a wrapper to the method: IWorkspace.build().

Examples:

```
<eclipse.incrementalBuild/>
<eclipse.incrementalBuild project="MyProject" kind="incremental"/>
```

> project the name of the project to be built
>
> kind the kind of build to perform. Possible values include:
>
> "incremental" to perform an incremental build
>   "full" to discard existing builder state and rebuild everything from scratch
>   "clean" to discard existing builder state but not rebuild
>
> builder the name of the builder to run; If this value is not specified all builders are run

**References**

- [org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore: CORE_JAVA_BUILD_RECREATE_MODIFIED_CLASS_FILES_IN_OUTPUT_FOLDER](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html#CORE_JAVA_BUILD_RECREATE_MODIFIED_CLASS_FILES_IN_OUTPUT_FOLDER)
- [Ant Eclipse Tasks: Ant tasks provided by the platform](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_eclipse_tasks.htm)
- [The Architecture of Open Source Applications: Eclipse](http://www.aosabook.org/en/eclipse.html)
- [HeadlessBuilder.java\core\internal\managedbuilder\cdt\eclipse\org\src\org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core\build - org.eclipse.cdt.git - Main CDT repo.](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/internal/core/HeadlessBuilder.java)
- [How to Train the JDT Dragon (pdf)](https://www.eclipsecon.org/2012/sites/eclipsecon.org.2012/files/How%20To%20Train%20the%20JDT%20Dragon%20combined.pdf)
- [Troubleshooting headless Ant builds with Rational Application Developer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0505_weisz/0505_weisz.html)
- [Use command-line Ant to build Eclipse Ant project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451569/use-command-line-ant-to-build-eclipse-ant-project)
- [org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs](https://github.com/otaviopires/eclipse/blob/master/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs)
- [Plug-in Development Environment Guide > Tasks > PDE Build > Advanced Topics:
  Compiler options](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_compiler_options.htm)